# What does the line in the code below does?

Tags: php, joomla-4.x

`$hasContent = empty($this->item->module) ||  isset($this->item->xml->customContent);`

> line 23 in /administrator/components/com_modules/tmpl/module/edit.php

Comment: This is kind of not a great question, here's why... 1. You have posted a "code dump", in other words, there isn't a lick of research/effort displayed.  2. Your question is Broad. We don't know you, nor your understanding of PHP/Joomla; ergo we don't know how basic to begin our explanation and we don't know the depth of detail which you require to get back on track with your development.  Do you need to know what the properties mean? What they might contain? Do you understand the usage of the php functions and the `||` operator?

Comment: Finally, if we help, is this question posted in such a way that is likely to be found and be deemed helpful to future researchers? I mean, the mission here is to help lots of people by serving individual people.   Please edit your question and include what you know, what you don't understand, and probably most valuable -- why do you need to comprehend this line of code. Is this part of a larger issue that you are experiencing? Tell us about it; we're here to help.

Comment: I didn't bother to correct the English in the title, because the whole title should be scrapped when you edit.  No one is going to be Googling for any part of that title.  I am downvoting your question, but will happily retract it if you can sufficiently improve your question.

Comment: Welcome to the community TirelessWorker.  It's great that you want to know about Joomla! You will find the help you need here, Mick has given you some great advice which will help you to find the answer.  You might also find help in a user group if there is one near you: https://community.joomla.org/user-groups.html give us more information about what you are trying to achieve (what problem you are solving) and I'm sure you will get the information you need.  I think possibly this is related to the other question and you are looking in the wrong place.  See @irata answer in your other q

Answer (score 1):

Sets a value to $hascontent if either of the conditions on the right side is true. The conditions appear to be is the module empty or is customContent set, i.e. not null.

If you want to find out what the value is that is set then use the following to display it.

```
echo print_r($hascontent);
```

or

```
echo var_dump($hascontent);
```